# Run python script after apk is generated successfully

Tags: android, python, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a system where after some user input I call                 `os.system("./gradlew assembleDebug ")` to get an APK generated. After this there is a function defined to download the APK, which gets called. This all works well in local environment. But on my AWS EC2 instance the former call is not a blocking one and the download apk function get called even when APK generation is in process, which obviously fails. I am using ngnix on my EC3 instance.

I want to call a python script after my apk is generated successfully.

This is in my build.gradle file.

```
task generateSources << {
        def script = "python downloadAPK.py".execute()
    }

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    compileJava.dependsOn(generateSources)
}
```

I am getting this error Error:(84, 0) Could not find property 'compileJava' on project ':app'.

Anyways I think that this won't help me, since I am not sure if this will run after APK generation. So I see two things that could be done here:

1. Configure the ngnix or something else on my instance which makes the former call a blocking one.
2. Call a python script after the APK is generated. May be go in assembleDebug command and call a python script after build is successful.

Please let me know which one is a better approach and how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a trick of groovy.  `GString#execute()` is not blocking by default.  However we can make it blocking by waiting for the exitValue.

So your code would work if you changed

```
task generateSources << {
    def script = "python downloadAPK.py".execute()
}
```

to wait for the `Process` to end before letting the task complete

```
task generateSources(dependsOn: assembleDebug) << {
    def process = "python downloadAPK.py".execute()
    // Wait till the process completes before continuing
    int exitValue = process.waitFor()
    println "Process exited with value $exitValue"
}
```

Then when you build just run `gradlew generateSources` and since that task depends on `assembleDebug` running first the apk will always be generated before the task runs.  This probably also means the `Process#waitFor` is pointless since it executes after the APK is generated

Comment: Thanks. But how do I know that this task will be called after build is successful?

Comment: @HarshVardhan, updated answer to add a dependsOn params to task creation.  Or instead of supplying as a param you could do `generateSources.dependsOn(assembleDebug)`